# WORDPRESS - Default blocks loaded on new post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Is is possibile, when creatin a new post, custom post type or page, to be loaded with all the blocks automatically for the layout?

Comment: Do you mean to have several templates and decide in which format to display the content before publishing the post or tab?

Comment: Thanc you. I mean having a predefined template of blocks already loaded on new page or post creation in the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

If you're [registering a new custom post type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/), use the `template` attribute and then create a nested array with the block's name and another nested array with any of the [block's attributes](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-attributes/) that you want to fill out. If you don't know a block's attributes, you can typically find them the block's block.json file

An example for the custom post type as follows:

```
'template' => array(
            array(
                'core/paragraph',
                array(
                    'align'   => 'center',
                    'content' => 'Place content you already in the block, even a link to a site like <a href="stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>.',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'core/buttons',
                array(
                    'layout' => array(
                        'type'           => 'flex',
                        'justifyContent' => 'center',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    array(
                        'core/button',
                        array(
                            'text'      => 'button text',
                            'url'       => 'https://the-url.com/',
                            'className' => 'a-custom-class-name',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

For existing post types, create a callback function that you hook into `init` as shown in the [Gutenberg documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-templates/#api).

Comment: @iamrobertsillo welcome; don't forget to mark it as answer if you found it to satisfy your question - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work